# Add controls to another Winform programatically C# .NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am having mother form now, I want to create a new form programatically. I created the new form but I couldn't add controls to the form.

```
private void CreateWindows()
    {
        newWindow = new Form();
        Application.Run(newWindow);

        newWindow.Activate();

        newWindow.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 40);

       Label label1 = new Label();

       newWindow.Controls.Add(label1);  

       label1.Text = "HI";
       label1.Visible = true;
       label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 24);
       label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 24);

    }
```

I have tried the codes above, the new form showed but I couldn't see the label1.

I appreciate any helps.

Comment: Also, it would be better to add the control once it has its properties set.

Comment: Is this called from a form event? If yes you should *not* be using `Application.Run` here. Use `Form.Show()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: add the controls to [`newWindow.Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx).

Second: Do it before [`Application.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run.aspx) because it will show the form and then wait for it to close (note: the way the designer does it is to add them at the constructor of a class that derived from [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Form.aspx)).

```
private void CreateWindows()
{
    newWindow = new Form();
    //Application.Run(newWindow); //Not here

    //newWindow.Activate(); //Wont do anything

    newWindow.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 40);

    Label label1 = new Label();

    newWindow.Controls.Add(label1); //Good

    label1.Text = "HI";
    label1.Visible = true;
    label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 24);
    label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 24);

    Application.Run(newWindow); //Here instead
}
```

Third: if you have already used `Application.Run` in the current thread (say because you are doing this from a form), then there is no point to call it here. Use [`Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show.aspx) or [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog.aspx) instead.

---

Also consider adding controls this way:

```
private void CreateWindows()
{
    newWindow = new Form();
    newWindow.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 40);

    newWindow.Controls.Add
    (
        new Label()
        {
            Text = "HI",
            Visible = true,
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 24),
            Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 24)
        }
    );
    Application.Run(newWindow);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the add controls after setting up the properties of label and then Show the new window.

```
private void CreateWindows()
{
    newWindow = new Form();

    newWindow.Activate();

    newWindow.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 40);

   Label label1 = new Label();


   label1.Text = "HI";
   label1.Visible = true;
   label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 24);
   label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 24);

   newWindow.Controls.Add(label1);  
   newWindow.Show();
   //use this if you want to wait for the form to be closed
   //newWindow.ShowDialog();

}
```

Comment: You should remove `Application.Run`.