# Adding a control and its process

Tags: c#

Just a question on the creation of a control such as a button or textbox in C#.  As I'm very new to this.

When I create a button on a form and call it myButton is this all that is needed in order to access it?  I have read elsewhere that following the creation of the button I need to add the following in code:

```
Button myButton = new Button();
```

Why would I need to do this since I already created the button by selecting it from the Toolbox and adding it to the form?

Also if I needed to add another button do I just add the following new code and not have to use the Toolbox again?

```
Button myButton1 = new Button();
```

If so what about the position and all?

Comment: Click and drag a button onto your form, either right click the button and press view ode or double click it

Comment: You might find a suitable answer there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288629/add-controls-to-another-winform-programatically-c-sharp-net

Comment: At design time you should only need to drag & drop the control onto the form - all of the rest of the work is automatically done for you. If you want to programmatically add controls at run time - that is a bit more complex. If you want help with that you will need to specify the platform - WInforms, WPF, etc.

Comment: The toolbox would have added that code for you. See your .designer.cs file for that form.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.  I may not have explained what I was asking properly.  What I wanted to know is if I need to do the following 'Button myButton = new Button();' when I add a new button.  Also when I decide to add another button what is the process.  Do I just use the toolbar or use the code as above?

Comment: You just drag and drop,the rest code is auto generated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WPF, you don't need to do that. You just need to drag where you want the button to be and then double click it to generate the code for you. Winforms might be different.